# Use R shiny to simulate CLT by using different distribution

Tags: r, shiny

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Central Limit Theorem Simulation"),
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            numericInput("sample.size", "Size of each random sample", 
                         value = 30, min = 1, max = 100, step = 1),
            sliderInput("simulation", "THe number of simulation",
                        value = 100, min = 100, max = 1000, step = 1),
            selectInput("sample.dist", "Population Distribution where each sample is from",
                        choices = c("Binomial","Poisson", "Normal", "Uniform") ),
            numericInput("bins", "Number of bins in the histogram", 
                         value = 20, min = 1, max = 50, step = 1),
            submitButton(text = "Submit")
        ),
        mainPanel(
            h3('Illustrating outputs'),

            h4('mean of random sample mean'),
            textOutput(outputId = "output_mean" ),

            h4('variance of random sample mean'),
            textOutput(outputId = "output_var"),

            h4("Table"),
            tableOutput(outputId = "output_table"),

            h4('histogram of random normal sample'),
            plotOutput(outputId = "output_hist") 
        )
  )


))


server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

    # Return the random sample
    rsample <- ifelse(
        input$sample.dist == "Binomial", rbinom(input$sample.size * input$simulation, 1, 0.5),
        ifelse(input$sample.dist == "Poisson", rpois(input$sample.size * input$simulation, 1),
               ifelse(input$sample.dist == "Normal", rnorm(input$sample.size * input$simulation),
                      runif(input$sample.size * input$simulation) ) ) )

    # Return the random sample matrix
    rsample.matrix <- matrix(rsample, nrow = input$simulation)

    # output mean of sample mean
    output$output_mean <- renderText({
        sample.mean <- rowMeans(rsample.matrix)
        mean(sample.mean)
    })

    # output variance of sample mean
    output$output_var <- renderText({
        sample.mean <- rowMeans(rsample.matrix)
        var(sample.mean)
    })

    # output histogram of sample mean
    output$output_hist <- renderPlot({
        sample.mean <- rowMeans(rsample.matrix)
        ggplot(data.frame(sample.mean), aes(x = sample.mean)) +
            geom_histogram(bins = input$bins)
    })

})


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

(1) The above codes are to create a shiny application to simulate random sample and verify Central Limit Theorem. However， since I just learned shiny, I have no idea where it is wrong.

(2) Also, if I want to change the parameter of a specific distribution based on the distribution selected by the user, what should I do?

The error returned from Rstudio is as follows:

```
Warning: Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext: Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)
Stack trace (innermost first):
    49: .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext
    48: .subset2(x, "impl")$get
    47: $.reactivevalues
    46: $ [#4]
    45: server [#4]
     4: <Anonymous>
     3: do.call
     2: print.shiny.appobj
     1: <Promise>
Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext() : 
  Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)
```

Answer (score 1):

The error says that code should be within a `reactive` or an `observe` statement. Have a look how I wrapped and used the variables

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Central Limit Theorem Simulation"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      numericInput("sample.size", "Size of each random sample", 
                   value = 30, min = 1, max = 100, step = 1),
      sliderInput("simulation", "THe number of simulation",
                  value = 100, min = 100, max = 1000, step = 1),
      selectInput("sample.dist", "Population Distribution where each sample is from",
                  choices = c("Binomial","Poisson", "Normal", "Uniform") ),
      numericInput("bins", "Number of bins in the histogram", 
                   value = 20, min = 1, max = 50, step = 1),
      submitButton(text = "Submit")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      h3('Illustrating outputs'),

      h4('mean of random sample mean'),
      textOutput(outputId = "output_mean" ),

      h4('variance of random sample mean'),
      textOutput(outputId = "output_var"),

      h4("Table"),
      tableOutput(outputId = "output_table"),

      h4('histogram of random normal sample'),
      plotOutput(outputId = "output_hist") 
    )
  )


))


server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  # Return the random sample
  rsample <- reactive({
    ifelse(
      input$sample.dist == "Binomial", rbinom(input$sample.size * input$simulation, 1, 0.5),
      ifelse(input$sample.dist == "Poisson", rpois(input$sample.size * input$simulation, 1),
             ifelse(input$sample.dist == "Normal", rnorm(input$sample.size * input$simulation),
                    runif(input$sample.size * input$simulation) ) ) )
  })

  # Return the random sample matrix
  rsamplematrix <- reactive({
    matrix(rsample(), nrow = input$simulation)
  })

  # output mean of sample mean
  output$output_mean <- renderText({
    sample.mean <- rowMeans(rsamplematrix())
    mean(sample.mean)
  })

  # output variance of sample mean
  output$output_var <- renderText({
    sample.mean <- rowMeans(rsamplematrix())
    var(sample.mean)
  })

  # output histogram of sample mean
  output$output_hist <- renderPlot({
    sample.mean <- rowMeans(rsamplematrix())
    ggplot(data.frame(sample.mean), aes(x = sample.mean)) +
      geom_histogram(bins = input$bins)
  })

})


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Pork! Just one more question: why is reactive function supposed to be used here? I am still confused about that.

Comment: Well, its by design. If you want to use the client `input` variables and manipulate them, they have to be wrapped in a dynamic call, such as a function, because it has to be able to translate to `HTML` if necessary. So all of the manipulation have to be used as a function with brackets `()`

Comment: There is another bug. Why the simulation cannot return the correct results? Right now all the sample are actually one number once it is simulated. For example, if the input$sample.size * input$simulation = 1000, all 1000 numbers are the same.

Comment: You have to inspect your code yourself. Also try not to use `.` when creating variables